# Phase accumulation model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics

In studying surface states I learned phase accumulation model which says the bound surface state formation condition is satisfied if the sum of phase shifts at the surface and interface equal the integer product of 2pi. I can understand the phase shift when there is a surface barrier potential or interface barrier potential by solving Schrodinger equation. But how to understand the phase shift for a bound state between two potential barriers? In short, how to calculate the phase shift for a step potential when there is another step potential in the symmetric position?

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in the existence of the other potential barrier does not affect the reflection coefficient of the original potential barrier.